# Windows Azure Service Bus Queues - MessageSender or QueueClient?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-queues

#### Backstory:

A few months ago (when I was new to Azure Queues and the SDK tools out there) I Googled "how do I do this" and "how do I do that"... here is where I am today:

1. I'm using a `QueueClient` (Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging - Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll) to receive messages from an Azure Queue.
2. In my same program I'm also using a `MessageSender` (from the same namespace and dll) to send messages to the Azure Queue.
3. My program has to track a `Dictionary<string, QueueClient>` and a `Dictionary<string, MessageSender>` - which is more complicated than it should be.

Now that I'm more familiar with the Azure SDKs... I realize that the `QueueClient` class can both **send and receive**... So why am I keeping track of 2 objects when the first one can do both?

#### Question:

Is there any reason to use the `MessageSender` class instead of the `QueueClient` class?

If I need to send and receive, shouldn't I just use the `QueueClient` class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK - I should have just reflected the DLL first... found the answer.

`QueueClient` is a class that simply has a `MessageSender` object and a `MessageReceiver` object inside of it. So the answer is **"No, you should not have 2 objects to do the same thing"**.

### Reflected code of the "Send" method:

```
public void Send(BrokeredMessage message)
{
    this.ThrowIfSenderNull("Send");
    this.InternalSender.Send(message);
}
```

The "InternalSender" object above is of type `MessageSender`.

Answer (score 11):

We have exposed the two different object to support symmetry and ease-of-use. As you are aware we have [Topics/Subscriptions](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/service-bus-topics/) as well as [Queues](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/service-bus-queues/). If you are just using Queues then you can create a QueueClient and achieve all the operations needed thru that. But say you later wanted to move to a Topic/Subscription publish-subscribe model. Programming against a generic [MessageSender](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagesender.aspx) and [MessageReciever](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagereceiver.aspx) will allow you to change the underlying topology and not have to modify any code (just the [address urls/names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh322642.aspx)). Thus you can write code that can work both in Queue as well as Topic/Subscription scenarios.

Comment: If MessageReceivers/Senders do the job of Topic/Subscription/Queue Clients,  plus they are more flexible and future-proof, why would one ever need xxxClients in the first place? What is the advantage of xxxClients over MessageReceivers/Senders?